# How can I locate available servers in android?

Tags: java, android, network-protocols

I am having trouble finding information on how to locate available network servers through android. I am hoping someone on here can point me in the right direction. The application I am coding requires the user to locate the server the application will communicate with from a list of all available network devices. I am wondering how I would go about doing this in java. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What kind of servers? Can you please explain more?

Comment: I want to find any available server listening on port 80

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't want to do that...there are a LOT of servers out there listening on port 80. Are you talking about specific servers that you own?

Comment: yes, the servers are going to be on a local network. I want the user of the application to be given a list of available servers on their network, than they pick the one they want to use.

Comment: Doing some research, it seems that unless the device is rooted, you won't be able to listen for servers on port 80.  Check out these links:  http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/fb59482a8b68c683#   
http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/660123ca64ba1229#

Comment: ok, thank you that was helpful, i didn't know about ports below 1024 being reserved for root user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i decided to give up on having the user select their server from a list. I now have the user enter the ip address and than check if the ip address is correct by using:

> .isReachable(int timeout);

thanks for the responses.